# How to do a POST or UPDATE on restful api server

Tags: rest, delphi, server

I'm currently building a restful API server for my mobile devices to access a mySQL database. The mobile apps need to be able to get data from the server, and also insert and edit data.

I have managed to successfuly do a GET from the server, but I'm stuck at how to get do the post. On the WebModuleUnit I added an action, with the following properties:
MethodType mtGet
Name actImsDocuments
PathInfo /imsDocuments

```
procedure TWebModule1.WebModule1actImsDocumentsAction(Sender: TObject;
  Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
  var
  qryDocuments: TFDQuery;
  JsonArray: TJSONArray;
  JsonObject: TJSONObject;
begin
 // Configure response
 Response.ContentType := 'application/json; charset=utf-8';

//Search for my clients table
qryDocuments := TFDQuery.Create(nil);
with qryDocuments do
begin
  Connection := FDConnection1;
  Active := false;
SQL.Clear;

Open('SELECT * FROM ims_document');

if qryDocuments.RecordCount > 0 then //if there is items
begin
   JsonArray := TJSONArray.Create;
   try
     First;
     while not EoF do //Iterate all items in the FDQuery
     begin
       JsonObject := TJSONObject.Create;
       AddFieldsToJSON(JsonObject, qryDocuments);
       JsonArray.AddElement(JsonObject);
       Next;
     end;
   finally
      Response.Content := JsonArray.ToString;
      JsonArray.DisposeOf;
   end;
end;
 end;
end;

    procedure TWebModule1.AddFieldsToJSON(AJsonObject: TJSONObject;
       AQuery: TFDQuery);
       begin
        with AQuery do
        begin
          AJsonObject.AddPair('number', TJSONNumber.Create(FieldByName('number').AsInteger));
          AJsonObject.AddPair('document_title', FieldByName('document_title').AsString);
       end;
    end;
```

Now this all above works perfectly, what I have no idea how to do, is how do I for example, edit a record in the table, or insert a new record, how do I get the values from the mobile device. I have no idea how to do a post, or update. Can anyone just give me an example of code please, as I have looked everywhere and just cannot get a clear understanding of this.

If I change the property of the action to mtPost, how would my code differ If I wanted to add a record to the table?

Comment: You could just use a TFDQuery component and then use a SQL UPDATE statement or just do another SELECT and filter on the record ID. Then you can use the TDataSets ‘edit’ and ‘post’ or ‘delete’ methodes.

Comment: I understand that I can use an INSERT INTO in SQL or use the normal table insert and post, but the part I do not understand is how do I read the values that comes from the device into the server. Do I write similar code to the code above, and then just use the ASjonObject to read the values of the incoming device to insert or edit a table?

Comment: Basicly yes, the ‘request’ object should have a property containing the posted (json) data, which you then can read to update the values of the table/db.